# spark-submit does not work with my jar located in hdfs

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, spark-submit

Here is my situation:

Apache spark version 2.4.4

Hadoop version 2.7.4

My application jar is located in hdfs.

My spark-submit looks like this:

```
/software/spark-2.4.4-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/spark-submit \
--class com.me.MyClass --master spark://host2.local:7077 \
--deploy-mode cluster \
hdfs://host2.local:9000/apps/myapps.jar
```

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.tracing.SpanReceiverHost.get(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/apache/hadoop/tracing/SpanReceiverHost;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:634)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:619)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:149)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2598)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2632)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2614)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:370)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:144)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveGlobPaths$2.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:139)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.WrappedArray.foreach(WrappedArray.scala:35)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.flatMap(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveGlobPaths(DependencyUtils.scala:139)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveAndDownloadJars$1.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:61)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$$anonfun$resolveAndDownloadJars$1.apply(DependencyUtils.scala:64)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.DependencyUtils$.resolveAndDownloadJars(DependencyUtils.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.setupDependencies(DriverWrapper.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:60)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)
```

Any pointer how to solve this, please?
Thank you.

Comment: try this address. `hdfs:///apps/myapps.jar`

Comment: Lamunas, Thanks for your reply. This did not work and I continue to get the same error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to transfer the jar into cluster, you can run your jar from your local id itself with executable permission.
Once your application is build transfer the .jar to your unix user account and give it executable permissions. Have a look at the below spark submit:-

spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster  --queue default 
  --files "full path of your properties file" --driver-memory 4G
 --num-executors 8 --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 4G 
  --class "main class name"
"full path of the jar which you have transferred to your local unix id"

You can use other spark submit configuration parameters if you want. Please note that in some version you have to use spark2-submit instead of spark-submit if there are multiple spark version involved.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how do we run a jar to deploy in cluster mode?

Comment: I have edited the above answer and you can see that i have passed cluster to the deploy mode flag i.e.  (--deploy-mode cluster) . This will help you launch your job in cluster mode.

Comment: As you can see in my original post that I had --deploy-mode cluster and that did not work. I could not make it work via spark-submit. However, the job submission through Rest API worked.

Answer (score 0):

`--deploy-mode cluster` will help in this case. taking the jars to cluster will be taken care by yarn cluster.